# as3 HTTP Request for BB Playbook Tablet

Tags: actionscript-3, http, request, blackberry-playbook

I am developing an app for blackberry playbook and I need to make http request. And I can't find available class for it. Tried to use mx.rpc.http.HTTPService class but it's not available. May be its a trivial question, but I'm realy stuck.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually that HTTPService class is available, as is flash.net.URLLoader.  If you can't get your setup to find HTTPService, you've got it configured incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

For [mx.rpc.http.mxml.HTTPService](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/AccessingData/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fdc.html) try adding the namespace thingy:

```
xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
```

and add **frameworks\libs\mx\mx.swc** to the Flex Build Path in Flash Builder